# How do I convert a greyscale height map to .3ds format?

Tags: image, 3dsmax, file-format, heightmap

I was given some height maps to use for game development, but they are in grayscale PNG format. How can I convert them to 3DS format?

Comment: Easiest would be to convert them to OBJ and then load this OBJ with 3DS Max.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered, what I did was download the free trail of 3ds max. I then created a flat plane is displaced this by the PNG. I could then export this as a .3ds file.

Answer (score 2):

As tkausl suggests, it should be trivial to program a simple tool:

- Construct 2D grid
- Apply heights from the image
- Write it to OBJ format file
- Import into 3DMax

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with 3DMax in several years, but it should be pretty simple to generate a 2D grid primitive/object and apply displacement texture (your heightmap image) to it along the vertical axis. Then freeze the geometry.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to, you could use the Assimp file import library's 3ds export function to create the 3ds files directly.

The procedure would be as follows:

- Load Image
- Process it into a vertex and index list.
- Add those to the aiScene structure.
- Export it using the 3ds exporter.

Also, if you are writing your game's code, or if the engine supports it, consider loading the image directly to the game and using it there. If there is a specific function like that, it usually should be much faster than simple model files, due to 2 reasons:

- When rendering you don't have to render Triangles but Triangle strips.
- Collision engines usually implement heightfield collision with a simpler test than for complex meshes.